Selecting Data in laravel using ajax
I made a configurator of matador in which user inserts its width, height, length, color and other details etc. I want to do that when user enters its id in url so it fetches all the record which he or she stores in database.
public function view($id)
{
    $formData = FormData::findOrFail($id);
    if (!$formData) {
        abort(404);
    };

    return view('polebar', ['formData'=> $formData]);   
}

This is controller file
Route::post('/quote/{id}', [FormController::class, 'view'])->name('quote.view');

This is route
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route("/quote/") }}',
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("response", response);
                if (response.status) {
                    alert('Data saved successfully!');
                    window.location.href = '/quote/' + response.quote_id;
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
            }
        });
   

This is ajax
I want that the data fetch from database it just changes its value in front-end and the result shows me in json

route("/quote/") There is no route with that name



// controller file
    public function view($id)
    {
        $formData = FormData::findOrFail($id);
        
        return view('polebar', ['formData'=> $formData]);   
    }

// Ajax code
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var Id = 1; // mention accurate id
    $.ajax({
        url: '/quote/' + Id,
        method: 'GET',
        data: {}, // You can pass additional data if needed
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("response", response);
            if (response.status) {
                alert('Data fetched successfully!');
                window.location.href = '/quote/' + response.quote_id;
            } else {
                alert('Failed to fetch data.');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
        }
    });

// Route file
    Route::get('/quote/{id}', [FormController::class, 'view'])->name('quote.view');

note: modify ajax code.




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
